# Create a list of variables of a function

Tags: variable-definitions, variable

How can I create a list of variables of simple functions with arguments? These functions will be defined by the user, to be manipulated with some code later.

```
f1[x1_,x2_,x3_]:=x1*x2-x3;
f2[y1_,y2_]:=y1/y2;
f3=[z1_,z2_,z3_,z4_]:=z1+z2+z3-z4;
```

I want the lists to be:

```
(* {x1, x2, x3} *)
(* {y1, y2} *)
(* {z1, z2, z3, z4} *)
```

Comment: There could be a lot of bullet-proofing needed here.  What if the user "accidentally" defines `f1[x1_, x2_] := x1 * x2` in addition to the three-argument definition you give?  What response would you want?

Comment: I agree. Actually, the goal is just do a function to create a list of variables, so it is not necessary to do it by hand. I (user) define the functions and MMA create the lists... of course, junk in, junk out ....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
In[4]:= ReleaseHold[List @@@ # & /@ Part[DownValues /@ {f1, f2, f3}, All, 1, 1, {1}]] /. Pattern -> (# &)

Out[4]= {{x1, x2, x3}, {y1, y2}, {z1, z2, z3, z4}}
```